# I want to create a log file for Android 5.0 using logcat

Tags: android

I want to create a log file for Android 5.0. I am using logcat with no filter, still it is only showing me the log of my application instead of all the applications. It should have shown me the complete log of Android System.

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Logs");
    // if external memory exists and folder with name Notes
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs(); // this will create folder.
    }
    file = new File(root, "log.txt");  // file path to save
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either download the SDK and use **adb logcat** or get **aLogcat** from the Market, which shows the log directly on your phone.

With Android 4+ the full system log is only visible if you have **ROOT**. Apps can only see their own log messages. For more information view

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/problems-accessing-message-logs-on-jelly-bean-with-alogcat/28853#28853